# How to run a gui client os in a virtual machine on non gui linux host?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

Is it possible to run a windows gui client in a virtual machine hosted in a non gui linux?

How to set this up? and how to connect to such a machine?

Comment: Do you mean a headless vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, if you have a *third* machine where you can run a GUI.  For instance, I've setup Windows 7 running in Xen server (a bare-metal hypervisor with only ssh access to the *server*).  I connected to it using RDP (remote desktop), from other Windows machines as well as using an RDP client on OS X.

Comment: Another machine is definitely no problem. Do you know if this is this possible on KVM or is it only available on Xen server? 
Also, how does the installation process work? You load the disk and remote in to install the os? How can you remote desktop into windows before the network settings are set?
Do you know of any good articles which can lead me through this process?

Comment: The answer is general enough: RDP cannot tell what the hypervisor is.  As usual, you have to resolve networking/connectivity issues.  For *installing* windows without a GUI... In Xen server, I could connect with a VNC "console" from a management tool on a different machine.  There may be similar applications for KVM.

Comment: Understood, thanks - unfortunately I need windows gui.

Comment: "VNC console" is where to start, since it can run before your VM does networking - see [OpenStack Virtual Machine Image Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/index.html) for example.  By the way, we've discussed the original question, you should continue this in a new question.

Comment: `virt-viewer` is available on Windows and allows you to view the console of your KVM guest during boot and/or before guest networking starts. It's an alternative to VNC in @ThomasDickey's comment above, and uses the SPICE protocol.

Comment: I saw the mention of `virt-viewer` when I was looking for followups for the VNC.  According to the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-viewer) it can use either VNC or SPICE.  OP can decide how to use these replies.

Comment: Actually, I saw it mentioned first (per google) on an [IBM page](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaat/liaatkvmsecvirtviewer.htm), but decided OP might not find it as useful as the OpenStack link.

Comment: Thank you both, `virt-viewer` is exactly what I needed. Installed and confirmed to be working. The reason for `virt-vierwer` vs VNC console in Openstack is that I am not too familiar with OpenStack, so it is something I will look into in the future.